# How to run Postman test cases by helm and rollback to last successful version if any test fail

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am using Helm kubernetes deployment and I want to run the postman test cases before a final deployment, and if any test case fails then rollback (or retain the current deployment like Blue-Green deployment).
How to achieve this?

Comment: You can Define readiness probes to do this

Comment: Have you read about [Chart Tests](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-tests) in the Helm documentation?  Do you have any artifacts or source code so far?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the expected behavior with [Helm Chart Tests](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_tests/) and the [postman/newman Docker image](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman-docker).

My Helm template for the test execution:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: API Test
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test-success
spec:
  containers:
    - name: PostmanTest
      image: postman/newman:latest
      args:
        - run
        - <url-to-postman-collection>
        # In case you need to define the hostname in the collection
        # Use {{baseUrl}} in the request URL
        - --env-var
        - baseUrl=<kubernetes-host-name>
```

After install the helm chart the tests can be executed with

> helm test